# Form_set_error for array of fields

Tags: forms

I got below code in form_validation

```
$form_state['values']['field_address'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0][postal_code];
```

I've tried below tricks but it didn't make red color in textbox.

```
form_set_error('field_address][postal_code', 'error');
form_set_error('field_address[und][0][postal_code', 'error');
form_set_error("field_address[und][0]['postal_code']", 'error');
form_set_error('field_address[LANGUAGE_NONE][0][postal_code', 'error');
```

Comment: Can you show the form?

Answer (score 0):

Your `form_set_error` like that

```
form_set_error('field_address][postal_code', t('enter postal code'.));
```

Comment: Please look my question and my tricks. I've already used this

Comment: that's right answers, there could be something other mistake.